# Get reference of a component and dispatch an event React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I am using a third party component that has an event which I would like to use on a click on a button. Event listener on that third party component is on some other event but I would like to dispatch that event when I click on a button. Can I do that?

Current Code

```
const customRef= useRef(null);
const dispatchThirdPartyEvent = () =>{
//I would like to dispatch an event here which is part of other library(third party component) that I am using. 
 console.log(customRef.current);
   
}
return (
    <>
<ThirdPartyComponent ref = {customRef}>
</ThirdPartyComponent>
</>
<button click ={dispatchThirdPartyEvent}> </button>
)
```

So I would like to dispatch an event on the click on a button which is part of other library(third party component) that I am using. Is that possible? I can get the reference of the object but I am not sure how can I dispatch an event

Comment: `click ={dispatchThirdPartyEvent}`

Comment: @shota How do I get the reference of the third party event? That is the question. I can call my method

Comment: Could you post what kind of component are you using?

Comment: @Shota I used useRef hook to get the reference but not sure if I can dispatch an event. I updated my question with reference